# is it possible to have multiple values in an *ngFor loop?

Tags: angular

so I have multiple nested arrays within one large nested array, and each element in the nested array is an object with the details of it.

these values are retrieved from multiple checkbox's from a 2D matrix (x and y) and for each selection of x and y the relevant details are shown in a table row (in their respective columns).

since these are nested arrays, code looks like this, (only showing )

```
<tbody *ngFor='let blend of selectedBlends'>
  <tr *ngFor='let bale of blend'/>
    <td>{{ bale.number }}</td>
    <td>{{ bale.weight }}</td>
    <td>{{ bale.value }}</td>
  </tr>
</body>
```

in this manner I have multiple <td>'s and accordingly each element in the nested array takes up two rows to display their data seperately, which is what I want.

however I also need to show the addition of both rows of bale.weight in the next column, so assuming row 1 of bale.weight is 25 and row 2 of bale.weight is 32, i cannot seem to get their values added together to display in the next column.

is there anyway to access the individual element values of the current index position of a *ngFor loop? or is something like the below code possible?

```
<tr *ngFor='let bale1, bale2 in blends'/>
```

the reason I am using nested arrays in one larger array is to check if the the same checkbox is clicked to remove it from my table displaying the data.

Comment: Can you please create a plunkr with exact template and real data. I can fork it and try help. Just cannot get what you exactly want to do?  `<tr *ngFor='let bale1, bale2 in blends'/>` this is not possible.

Comment: @Bud please replicate this issue in stackblitz or plunker with some data

Comment: Can you show , your data format and what are you trying. Because, It's hard to predict what you want, unless you clarify your question more?

Comment: thanks for the replies and offering to help, sorry i could not reply earlier as i was a little busy, i think the solution provided below by Chris should work with some modification. I will get back once i have tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you wrote I've tried to understand what you are doing. Since I have not seen your data structure I have also guessed on that, but I will provide the data structure I used.

NOTE: This solution requires you to pre-calculate each weight and put it into the proper object. For my example, I have just hardcoded it.

**UPDATE 11/6/2017: After verifying the requirements with the original poster, the Typescript file is being updated.**

**Typescript file:**

```
colNames = ['Number', 'Weight', 'Value', 'Total Weight'];
selectedBlends = [];

// scaffolded data that should reflect what is coming into the app
incomingData = [
    {
        bales: [
            {
                number: 1,
                weight: 10,
                value: '$10'
            },
            {
                number: 2,
                weight: 20,
                value: '$20'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        bales: [
            {
                number: 5,
                weight: 50,
                value: '$50'
            },
            {
                number: 6,
                weight: 60,
                value: '$60'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        bales: [
            {
                number: 9,
                weight: 90,
                value: '$90'
            },
            {
                number: 10,
                weight: 110,
                value: '$110'
            }
        ],
    }
];

constructor() {
    this.processBales(this.incomingData);   // I am passing the scaffolded data here. Likely optional
}

processBales(incomingData: any) {
    for (const data in incomingData) {
        if (incomingData.hasOwnProperty(data)) {
            this.createBalesObject(incomingData[data]);
        }
    }
}

createBalesObject (data) {
    this.selectedBlends.push({
        bales: data.bales,
        totalWeight: this.calculateTotalWeight(data.bales)
    });
}

calculateTotalWeight(bales) {
    let totalWeight = 0;
    for (const bale in bales) {
        if (bales.hasOwnProperty(bale)) {
            totalWeight += bales[bale].weight;
        }
    }
    return totalWeight;
}
```

**HTML file:** (I have removed stylings used to create the screen capture of the table for brevity)

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let col of colNames">
        {{col}}
      </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngFor="let blend of selectedBlends">
      <tr *ngFor="let bale of blend.bales; let index=index">
        <td>{{bale.number}}</td>
        <td>{{bale.weight}}</td>
        <td>{{bale.value}}</td>
        <td>
            <span *ngIf="index==1">{{blend.totalWeight}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The output table takes the two rows of data, sums the weights, and displays that in the final column. This is what I think you are saying in the question.

[image]

**Final Note:**
This code assumes that, based on your wording, you are working with 2 rows at a time. If not you need to change the `*ngIf` in the `<span>`

Comment: thanks for this solution, i will try this with a few amendments and get back to you, but you have got my data structure correct, unfortunately i cannot hardcode the value, i has to be calculated during the apps use. if you could, could you please explain why you used blend.bales in the second *ngFor condition? does it access the individual elements of the first *ngFor blend element?

Comment: The value doesn't need to be hard-coded.  I did it here purely for convenience. I'll be in front of a computer shortly and respond in the answer but to your other question: bales is an object that contains an array and a string so I addressed it this way.

Comment: @Bud - This updated typescript is more dynamic and will calculate the incoming data (assuming it is what I have in the scaffolded 'incoming data' object)